# CakePHP: How to retrieve data by multiple condition

Tags: php, cakephp

Please help me to retrieve data from a table by multiple condition in Cakephp
I have one table name: article; I have tried to retrieve data with the code below 
I want to get **specific id as given in the parameter; article_price > 0 and article_status > 1**

```
public function getArticle($artID = ''){
     return $this->find('all', array(
         'condition' => array(
                            'article_id =' => $artID, 
                            'article_price' => '> 0',
                            'article_status = ' => '1'),
         'order' => 'article_id DESC'
     ));
}
```

// the out put was selected all data without condition that I want. 
What was the problem with my code?
What I found out is I print: **echo $this->element ('sql_dump');** and I got the following sql statement:

```
SELECT `article`.`article_id`, `article`.`name`, `article`.`article_price`, `article`.`article_status` FROM `db_1stcakephp`.`article` AS `article` WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY `article_id` DESC
```

Please help me.
Thank!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your model name is Article:

```
public function getArticle($art_id) {
    return $this->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Article.article_id' => $art_id,
            'Article.article_price >' => 0,
            'Article.article_status >' => 1,
        ),
    ));
}
```

Using 'Model.field' syntax is optional, until your models have relationship and have the same names - for example Article.status and Author.status.

Moving comparison sign into array's key part allows you to do:

```
'Article.price >'   => $minPrice,
'Article.price <='  => $maxPrice,
```

And I didn't really notice typo in 'conditions'.

Comment: your answer contains the right solution, but you should really add some explanation as to *what* OP was doing wrong; e.g. `condition` should be `conditions` and the `>` should be in the *key* not the *value* of the conditions. Add a bit of extra info and I'll upvote

Comment: In order to combine multiple condition with an *OR* logic, wrap them in an `or` key. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions

Comment: @remiq thanks! Editing the answer really improved it and made it more informative, not just for the OP